# How to get only list of Folder name in FTP?

Tags: c#

How to get only the list of Folder name of ftp not the files names of that folder,suppose i have 4 folder (A,B,C,D) i want to get the 4 folder name only not files ? Working in c#.

i have seen code that gives the list of files .

i have tried this code and it is giving me the files name as well as the folder name, but i need only folders name only.

Regards
Haider

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string HtmlResult = String.Empty;
Console.WriteLine("Starting listing of files....");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpUrl);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpPassword);
request.UsePassive = false;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responsestream))
    {
        string _line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (_line != null && _line != String.Empty)
        {
            HtmlResult += _line;
            _line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }                    
}
//parse html output
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(HtmlResult);
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    if(node.InnerText.Contains(".txt")) FtpListing.Add(node.InnerText);
}
Console.WriteLine("{0} Files found", FtpListing.Count);
```

Comment: Hi Amit,

 Thanks for reply , i have tried this code and it is giving me the files name as well as the folder name, but i need only folders name only not the contents of that folder.

Comment: @user2728950 Try my updated answer